# Menú dinámico que resalte la palabra correspondiente a la página actual

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo una barra de navegación con tres elementos:

- Home
- Locations
- About us

Quiero que cambie el color de la palabra, correspondiente a la página actual.

Por ejemplo: si estoy en *home.index*, que sea resaltado el elemento *Home*.

```
<ul>                              
    <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Locations</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Al dar `.active` al elemento *Home*, este tendrá un estilo diferente de los otras dos.

Ahora, si hago clic en *Locations*, quiero que `.active` se le aplique a este elemento y no al anterior.

¿Cómo hago que esto sea dinámico al pasar de un documento a otro?

Comment: Usando únicamente JavaScript, una solución podría ser guardar en una cookie el id de la sección, y dependiendo del valor que le des a dicha cookie, poner la clase active al botón de la navegación.

Comment: Viviana. Bienvenida a StackOverflow en español. Como te comenta @Cheshire necesitamos ver tu código javascript para poder resolver el problema puntual que tienes. Puedes editar tu pregunta para agregarlo.

Comment: Se me ocurre hacerlo con javascript, obtener la `url` en la se esta actualmente, recorrer los `li > a` de mi menu, consultar si en mi `url` existe coincidencia con el un `href` quiza con indexOf, y si alguno coincide lo marco como activo y listo

Comment: Gracias Cheshire y Pak, soy superjunior con javascript, entiendo que voy a cambiar la clase mediante JS, pero no se como escribirlo, por eso no he agregado ningún codigo...

Comment: Una solución fácil sería dar al body un id. Por ejemplo si estás en `home.html` el body podría tener `<body id="home">` Si estás en `locations.html` el body podría tener `<body id="locations">`...etc.  Los elementos de la barra de navegación pueden tener una clase por ejemplo `<li class="home">`, `<li class="locations">`...etc. En el CSS puedes decir `#home .home, #locations .locations{/* aquí van los estilos para active*/}`

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como te han comentado, una buena idea sería establecer una cookie con el nombre de la sección activa. Para establecer el nombre de la sección activa en una cookie debes crear un evento que escuche el click en cada uno de los links y, antes de realizar la redirección, guardar el nombre de la sección a la cual nos vamos a dirigir.

Te adjunto un trozo de código que implementa esta funcionalidad.

```js
/**
 * Función que devuelve el valor de una cookie, dado
 *   su nombre de cookie.
 *
 * @param {string} name - Nombre de la cookie a obtener.
 **/
function getCookie(name) {
    var value = "; " + document.cookie;
    var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
    if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}

/**
 * Función que establece una cookie dado su nombre de cookie.
 *
 * @param {string} name - Nombre de cookie.
 * @param {string} value - Valor de cookie.
 **/
function setCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + (value || "")  + expires + "; path=/";
}


/**
 * Esta función es falsa, sirve para obtener el nombre de la sección
 *   activa aquí en el Fiddle de StackOverflow. Usa la función
 *   anterior en tu implementación real dándole un nombre a la cookie.
 *   Por ejemplo: getCookie('seccionActiva')
 **/
function getFakeCookie() {
    return "Home";
}

// Cuando se cargue la página
window.onload = function() {
    // ejecutamos esta función
    
    // Obtenemos el nombre de la sección activa de las cookies
    var nombreDeSeccionActiva = getFakeCookie();
    
    // Obtenemos cada elemento 'li' de la lista de secciones
    var secciones = document.querySelector("#sections").children;
    
    // Iteramos por todos los elementos de la lista de secciones
    for (var i=0; i<secciones.length; i++) {
        // Si este elemento es la sección activa
        if (secciones[i].innerText == nombreDeSeccionActiva) {
            // Le añadimos la clase 'active'
            secciones[i].classList.add("active")
        }
        
        // Al hacer click en el elemento
        secciones[i].onclick = function(e) {
            // Actualizamos la cookie de la sección activa
            setCookie("seccionActiva", secciones[i].innerText);
            
            // Nos dirigimos a la dirección a la que apunta
            //   el elemento en su atributo 'href'
            window.location.href = secciones[i].href;
        }
    }    
}
```

```css
.active {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
 <ul id="sections">                              
    <li>
        <a href="...">Home</a>                               
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="...">Locations</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="...">About us</a>
    </li>
</ul>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo no hacerlo estableciendo cookies, porque probablemente el usuario que acceda a tu sitio, tenga las cookies deshabilitadas y todo el funcionamiento se iría al traste, por no hablar de que tendrías que avisar del uso de cookies según la nueva normativa de protección de datos europea.

Te recomiendo lo más básico. Aquí no hay dinamicidad, lo dinámico es muy relativo.

Te recomiendo encarecidamente utilizar el siguiente método de ejemplo:

```css
ul
{
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande';
  font-size: .9em;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  width: 100%;
}

li
{
  background-color: #bf5af2;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

li:not(:last-child)
{
  margin-right: 1em;
}

li:hover
{
  background-color: #af52de;
}

li.active
{
  background-color: #5e5ce6;
}

li.active:hover
{
  background-color: #5856d6;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="active">Inicio</li>
    <li>Acerca de</li>
    <li>Prensa</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Lo único que debes hacer es cambiar la posición de la clase `.active` en cada página de tu sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que sería más práctico hacerlo usando javascript, con una funcion sencilla puedes ir cambiando la clase "active" de un elemento de la lista a otro.
Por ejemplo:

```
$("a").on("click", function(){
  changeTab(this);
});

function changeTab(target){
  if(!$(target).parent().hasClass("active")){
    console.log("entra");
    $("li").removeClass("active");
    $(target).parent().addClass("active");
  }
};
```